# Node JS for loop does not work

Tags: node.js

In node js, after running the for loop, descrip does not contain anything, no field written into the descrip array, why?

```
data = data['data'];
var course = data['course'];
data = data['sections'];
var descrip = new Array();
console.log(data.length);
for (var i = data.size - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    var data = data[i];
    var section = data['section'];
    var day = data['day'];
    var date = data['date'];
    var start = data['start_time'];
    var end = data['end_time'];
    var location = data['location'];
    var res = 'Section: '+section+'\nDate: '+date+' '+day+'\nLocation: '+location+'\nStart: '+start+'\tEnd: '+end;
    descrip.push(res);
};
```

Comment: Don't you mean `data.length`? You're referring to `data.size` there. Using `forEach(...)` largely avoids this.

Answer (score 2):

The length of an array in JavaScript is returned by the `length` property:

```
for (var i = data.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
     // no block scope in JS, using data as a variable name here overwrites array
    // var data = data[i];
    var _data = data[i];
    var section = _data['section'];
    var day = _data['day'];
    var date = _data['date'];
    var start = _data['start_time'];
    var end = _data['end_time'];
    var location = _data['location'];
    var res = 'Section: '+section+'\nDate: '+date+' '+day+'\nLocation: '+location+'\nStart: '+start+'\tEnd: '+end;
    descrip.push(res);
};
```

Also, as pointed out in the comments by @Red Alert, you're overwriting your `data` variable in the for loop (JavaScript has no concept of block scope). I've renamed it _data, but you could probably come up with a more meaningful name to distinguish between the array and the element of the current iteration.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you expect `data` to be an array, `data.size - 1` will be `-1` since `data.size` is `null`.  So it will exit the loop immediately.  You probably want `data.length`.

Comment: In Ruby `size` and `length` are synonymous, so this is easy to miss.